# Example of using RemoteObject from Flex with Gravity messaging service from GraniteDS

Tags: apache-flex, gravity, remoteobject, graniteds

I need an example about using RemoteObject from Flex with Gravity messaging service from GraniteDS. The only resource I managed to find about the topic can be seen here:
http://granite-data-services-forum.468750.n3.nabble.com/Does-Gravity-support-remote-objects-td684512.html

Thanks

Comment: Questions like this are considered "off topic" for Stack Overflow. Ideally, you would add more details about what you've tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

you need [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CE8QFjAE&url=http://java.dzone.com/articles/enterprise-ria-spring-3-flex-4&ei=WovyUdiDHsPXPI62gIgG&usg=AFQjCNGauvBZoZOkUhmrzE4ilWjk5RUhdw&sig2=EDL1pT-vvDba1pIkuvMIig&bvm=bv.49784469,d.ZWU&cad=rja) ?

search in google for: `graniteds flex example` and you are good to go